# View model absence in registration form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view that contains a registration form with the following fields:

1. E-Mail
2. First Name
3. Last Name
4. Password

I am posting the form using jQuery Ajax without using View Model.

**Question** : Is it a good approach to not use View Model in his context ?

**Question** : Is my approach useless in case of unit test cases?

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" })",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({mail : "mails", nam : nam ......}),
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("wsaved");
    }
});

[HpPost]
public Actionresult abc(string mail, string nam, sring lasnam)
{
     return Json(new {succss = ru});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good approach to not use View Model in his context ?

No, it will make validation much harder. Suppose that you wanted to validate that the email is not empty and is indeed a valid email address. If you used a view model, all you had to do is decorate the `Email` property on your view model with the correct validation attributes. With your approach you will now have to write a couple of useless lines of code in your controller action for that.

Here's how your view model might look like:

```
public class RegisterUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("PUT YOUR REGEX TO VALIDATE AN EMAIL HERE")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("PUT YOUR REGEX TO ENFORCE SOME PASSWORD STRENGTH")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and now your controller action becomes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // validation failed

        var errors = ModelState
            .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(x => new 
            { 
                Key = x.Key, 
                Errors = x.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage) 
            }
        );

        return Json(new { success = false, errors = errors });
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: No, it's not useless. The way you would unit test this controller action won't be influenced by whether you are using a view model or not.

Comment: You know,  some times , people like me (small/stupid developers only 60 reputation) thinks that, Darin is wrong... He is using View Model. then he may suggest Unobtrusive/Fluent Validation for client side. BUT, that may be correct. Isn't that large cut instead of short cut ? Because at the end you are saying my approach is good for Unit test cases . So is there any in-between approach, that suits my context for unit test cases and front end functionality ?

Comment: @SMC What you're losing with your approach though is the ability to do validation.  The ViewModel decorated with ValidationAttributes is more maintainable because not only will the client JS work if you enable jQuery validation, but the validation is ALSO done by the server code, which is far more important than any client side validation.  Never trust the client.

Comment: one confusions : Do I really need a View Model for such a short functionaliy, In case, I xclud unit test case from discussion? You know, compressing a 0 byte .txt file will produce 85 Bytes .zip file!!!

Comment: Unit testing is unrelated to view models. I think you are missing the whole point of view models. If you think that people use view models because that makes unit testing easier, then, I am afraid that you have completely misunderstood view models. Where did you see me mentioning anything about unit testing in my answer? Did you even read my answer? All I said is that view models would make validation easier in this case leading to cleaner and slimmer controller action. That's all I said in my answer. I remind you that it was you that brought unit testing into the picture with your comments.

Comment: And I tell you once again: whether you are using view models or not, this is completely unrelated to unit testing. So if you don't care about unit testing and never write tests about your code, you should probably wouldn't care much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using an ApiController with MVC 4, then you can use a Model to bind to, which will use (by default) Newton Json.NET.

ResponseModel

```
[DataContact]
public class ResponseModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

ActionModel

```
[DataContact]
public class RegisterUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember(isRequired=true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(isRequired="true")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

ApiController Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ReponseModel Register(RegisterActionModel actionModel)
{
    if (this.ModelState == valid)
    {
        //do stuff
        return new ResponseModel()
        {
            Status = "OK"
        };

    }
    else
    {
        return new ResponseModel()
        {
             Status = "Invalid Data"
        }
    }
}
```